# Many-to-many relationship with different other objects, self and attributes in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am declaring a somewhat complicated model with SQLAlchemy. I have basic objects like (fields are not important in that case):

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'as'

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bs'
```

Now I want to declare a collection of such objects, which would be easy with a simple `relationship`, but unfortunately, I need the followinf `class C`:

- A single field called `members` that can point to an arbitrary number of `A` and `B` objects
- It also needs to be able to contain references to other `C` objects as well.
- The mappings need to have an attribute attached to them.

I think the third bullet point is simple, as described at http://pythoncentral.io/sqlalchemy-association-tables/ . I do not know if the first one is possible, and I do not get my head wrapped around the second. I tried a simple `relationship('C')`, but that lead to SQLAlchemy complaining a lot about duplicate foreign key fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use **joined table inheritance** as described [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance).

First, add a common parent class for the similar classes, with a field named type (or anything else) as a discriminator…

```
class E(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'es'
    id = COlumn(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String)
```

…then add mapper arguments:

```
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'es',
        'polymorphic_on': type,
        'with_polymorphic': '*'
    }
```

Let the similar classes inherit from it…

```
class A(E):
    __tablename__ = 'as'
```

…and have them use a shared primary/foreign key and the correct mapper args:

```
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('es.id'), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'as'
    }
```

(Same goes for `B`)

A relationship can then be defined towards class `E`.

The relationship to the class containing the relationship itself just works if you leave out the backref.